# How to copy .pub file to ssh authorized_key

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, fedora, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have got .pub file from Beanstalkapp and I have downloaded it to my local machine, Now what i want to do is to copy this .pub to my AWS EC2 fedora instance so that I can deploy my files to the server via beanstalkapp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key needs to be present in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the user that your application runs under on the EC2 instance.

To accomplish this:

ssh into your EC2 instance:

```
ssh -i /path/to/your/amazon/private/key.pem your_ec2_user@your_ec2_instance_ip
```

Then check to see if you already have an authorized_keys file

```
cat .ssh/authorized_keys
```

If you do not have one, then create one

```
mkdir .ssh
cd .ssh
touch authorized_keys
chmod 600 authorized_keys
```

Then on your source machine, open your .pub in a text editor (or cat it in Terminal) and copy the contents to the clipboard.

Finally, using vi, vim, nano, or your text editor of choice append the contents of the .pub

Using vi:

```
vi authorized_keys
```

- scroll to the point where you want to insert the text
- press i to enter INSERT mode
- paste the contents of your .pub (CTRL/COMMAND V or Edit->Paste on the Terminal/PuTTY window)
- press `<ESCAPE>` to exit edit mode
- type :w! (colon w ! `<enter>`) to save a read-only file
- type :q and press `<enter>` to quit vi

Your .pub certificate is now on your EC2 instance.